# Quotations in a saved name upon initial save?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This code works, but something odd comes out of it, when I attempt to save the file, it shows up at `"Open Order Log - 10-4-12.xlsx"` instead of `Open Order Log - 10-4-12.xlsx` is there a reason for that?

`NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Open Order Log - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xlsx")`

Solved it:

`wbBK2.SaveAs Dir & Application.PathSeparator & "Open Order Report -" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & ".xlsx"`

It's a little bit of a twist, but it works.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior in MAC. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove the quotes, you have to use a filter.

```
NewFile=Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="StackOverflow.xlsx", _
             FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
```

note for Mac:
Be aware that there is a long time bug with
`getsaveasfilename`: ­ if the user navigates to the file using the disclosure
arrows, an incorrect path will be returned. However, if the directory nodes
are instead double clicked, the path will be correct.

Comment: I would think so, but I don't have a Mac to test it on, sorry.